# Calling workflow inside workflow

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am trying to read text files in a folder and read content through two work flows. Is it possible to call a workflow inside another workflow?

```
workflow ReadFilesFromFolder
{
     $folderPath = 'C:\Users\MyName\MyFolder'

     Get-ChildItem $folderPath -Filter *.txt | 
        Foreach-Object {
            ReadTextFile $_.FullName   
        }
}

workflow ReadTextFile
{
    param($path)

    $lines = Get-Content $path  
    ForEach -Parallel ($line in $lines)
    {        
            $line  
    }
}
```

PS: Foreach parallel only accepts workflows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to **explicitly** specify the parameters with their **names**. It also looks like you can't invoke the workflow within the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet - however `foreach` seems to work:

```
workflow ReadFilesFromFolder
{
     $folderPath = 'C:\Users\MyName\MyFolder'

     $items = Get-ChildItem $folderPath -Filter *.txt
     foreach($item in $items)
     {
         ReadTextFile -path $item.FullName   
     }
}

workflow ReadTextFile
{
    param($path)

    $lines = Get-Content $path  
    ForEach -Parallel ($line in $lines)
    {        
        $line  
    }
}
```

Comment: It throws error ReadTextFile is not recognized as a cmdlet.

Comment: You are right. It looks like you can't call it within the `Foreac-Object` cmdlet. However it works in a foreach loop. I will edit my answer.

Comment: there is some issue I guess. Get-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
'System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]'.
At PurgeStreamsFromFolder:3 char:3
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]

Comment: worked like a charm... I have typo in my code. Thanks for your time.